# How do I loop through all radio or checkbox inputs on a page and return what combination of values are returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of 4 groups of radio inputs. I need to loop through all of them and return the combination of the ones the user has selected so I can perform an action based on what the combination is. Right now I am just using a ton of if statements and I know I am doing this wrong. I would like to just loop through them and if combination x comes back then I can change the image displayed to a certain image, or if combination y comes back I can change to a different image. So what I am thinking I should do is define an array of checked radios for each possible outcome then check if one of those arrays is true after the loop is complete. If it is, display the corresponding image for that combination. Does that sound like the right approach? So currently I have it looping through and returning the values. When I check the radio columbia I expect array to be equal to array1 and it should alert me  but it isn't.

```
 <div class="controls">
                <div class="models">
                    <h4>Makes</h4>
                    <form>
                      <input id="coronado" type="radio" name="make" value="stock" checked> Coronado

                      <input id="columbia" type="radio" name="make" value="white"> Columbia
                    </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="models">
                    <h4>Models</h4>
                    <form>
                      <input id="day-cab" type="radio" name="model" value="day-cab" checked> Day Cab
                       <input id="mid-roof" type="radio" name="model" value="mid-roof"> Mid Roof

                      <input id="raised-roof" type="radio" name="model" value="raised-roof"> Raised Roof
                    </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="colors">
                    <h4>Colors</h4>
                    <form>
                      <input id="stock" type="radio" name="color" value="orange" checked> Stock

                      <input id="white" type="radio" name="color" value="white"> White
                    </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="accessories">
                    <h4>Accessories</h4>
                    <form>
                      <input id="stock-wheels" type="radio" name="accessories" value="stock-wheels" checked> Stock Wheels

                      <input id="with-spinners" type="radio" name="accessories" value="spinners"> Spinners
                    </form> 
                </div>

            </div>

var array = [];
var array1 = ["columbia","day-cab","orange","stock-wheels"];
$(':radio').change(function() {
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(i, e)  {
    array[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    if (array == array1) {
        alert(array);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are just really just objects under the hood so even comparing two empty arrays will return false.

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
array1 == array2 //evaluates to false
```

You either want to use another loop to iterate over the contents and compare each of the contents of one array to the other(which I believe would be O(n^2) time). Or you could store a stringified version of the Array on a hash table and then check the hash table in constant time. Another benefit is that you could store your image at the same location. I believe it would turn the lookup into a constant time operation O(1).

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var hashTable = {};
hashTable[JSON.stringify(array)] = (Your image here);
```

To compare your new array you would then just look it up like a normal key value pair lookup.

```
var img = hashTable[array];
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your answer as I am not familiar with hashtable and stringify. How would I go about implementing this? This method seems to work http://pastebin.com/QEHXQB0N but would require a bunch of if statements. What do you think?

Comment: In Javascript, and I believe only in Javascript we have the luxury that our objects are hash tables. So basically what you would be doing is calling JSON.stringify to turn the whole array, including brackets, into a string. Then you assign that string as the key in an object and you can put the intended value for the results of that particular array as the value. 

var myHashObject = {};
myHashObject[stringValueForArray] = my intended value
so then myHashObject would look like this.
myHashObject = {
  stringValueForArray: my intended value
}